# Url pattern for alphanumeric(slug) string in django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to make this url patterns work, but I am not getting anywhere.I get a page not found error.The url in my url bar is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tags/?Python`if I select python slug, but it does not use the defined url.
What I want to do is, open a new template with information related to slug. 
This is my view:

```
def tags(request,slug):
    verse = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'tags.html',{'verse':verse})
```

Here is my url:

```
 url(r'^tags/(?P<slug>[\W-]+)/$', views.tags),
```

This is my template:

```
Tagged under -  {% for i in verse.tags.all%}<a href='/tags'>{{ i }} | </a>{% endfor %}
```

I have tried passing a query string in template as:

```
/tags/q={{i}}
```

I have also tried to use:

```
{% url tags i.slug %}
```

(based on [Slug Url Regex in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886944/slug-url-regex-in-django))

But so far nothing is working. I want to open the tags template with the selected slug being displayed.

Comment: What is in views.tags? Also `[\W-]` can be replaced with `\W` since `-` is already matched with `\W` in Python.

Comment: @Andie2302 views.tags is the view that renders the tags template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you must set a name In `url` similar below:

```
url(r'^tags/(?P<slug>.+)/$', views.tags, name='tags'),
```

in template change your `url` tag to:

```
{% url "tags" slug=i.slug %}
```

Comment: Now i am getting NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'tags' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': u'Python'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tags/(?P<slug>\\W+)/$']

Comment: got it in the end. The problem was with my url too. I had to remove the [\W-] and replace it with a . to make it work